# Drupal MP4 videos not playing in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, video, drupal-7

I've added these 2 lines to our htaccess file, but the video shows a dark screen with No video with supported MIME type and format found:

```
AddType sites/default/files/videos/original/webm .webm
AddType sites/default/files/videos/original/mp4 .mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

`sites/default/files/videos/original/webm` and `sites/default/files/videos/original/mp4` aren't mime-types. You're probably looking for `video/webm` and `video/mp4`, respectively.